# Why does wordpress add Theme not list a specific theme anymore?

Tags: themes

I used a theme on a wordpress site that I liked and now a year later I cannot find that theme for a second installation in any of the add themes tabs.

Does it get removed when not updated or downloaded? Or is it only when the theme  developer removes it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official repositories will omit themes and plugins that hadn't been updated in two years from search and APIs. If you can find theme on repository site this is shown by following warning:

> This theme **hasn’t been updated in over 2 years**. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.

If theme is really *gone* and cannot be located on site then it was likely removed by author or repository team for some reason.

Comment: If wordpress discourages themes/plugins that is not "active" wouldn't it make sense to notify us if there either that has not been updated "recently" close to the update page.